# WooCommerce Product Google search results in different currencies

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

When searching products on my client's website, it comes up in both AUD and USD currencies. The desired currency is AUD only.
In WooCommerce > Settings - General - Currency is set to Australian dollar ($).

The listings have similar wordings and I can't see a repetitive pattern as to why some products are showing up in AUD and some in USD.

On product page source code, the Yoast SEO schema data (below) is showing AUD.

`<script type="application/ld+json">{"@context":"https:\/\/schema.org\/","@type":"Product","@id":"https:\/\/example.com.au\/product\/infintiy-studio-dragonball-z-1-4-future-trunks-resin-statue\/#product","name":"Infintiy Studio Dragonball Z 1\/4 Future Trunks Resin Statue","url":"https:\/\/example.com.au\/product\/infintiy-studio-dragonball-z-1-4-future-trunks-resin-statue\/","description":"Prices are all in Australian Dollars (AUD)\r\nETA March - June 2022 onwards\r\n\r\nAll Preorders are non refundable due to seller taking the time and effort to make the products to sell. Preorder payments are to guarantee that each product has been paid and made to order. Sorry for the inconvenience\r\n\r\nInvoice for remaining payment will be sent 2-3 weeks before product is available for shipping.\r\n\r\nInvoice for shipping will follow 1 week after.\r\n\r\nPlease pay on time to proceed with a smooth transaction and delivery\r\n\r\nDISCLAIMER: RESINS ARE VERY FRAGILE IN NATURE AND ALTHOUGH ALL PRODUCTS ARE PACKED VERY WELL THERE MIGHT BE TIMES RESINS ARRIVE WITH CLEAN SNAPS OR SCRATCHES ON PAINT. NO COMPENSATION WILL BE GIVEN FOR THESE FAULTS AS THEY CAN BE GLUED AND WE CAN\u2019T GUARANTEE PERFECTION IN EVERY SINGLE PRODUCT. DO NOT BUY IF YOU ARE NOT WILLING TO ACCEPT THIS","image":"https:\/\/cdn.example.com.au\/app\/uploads\/2021\/10\/WeChat-Image_20211019191749.jpg","sku":50085,"offers":[{"@type":"AggregateOffer","lowPrice":"400.00","highPrice":"1390.00","offerCount":2,"priceCurrency":"AUD","availability":"http:\/\/schema.org\/OutOfStock","url":"https:\/\/example.com.au\/product\/infintiy-studio-dragonball-z-1-4-future-trunks-resin-statue\/","seller":{"@type":"Organization","name":"Example Site","url":"https:\/\/example.com.au"}}]}</script>`

[image: Google search showing different prices in AUD and USD]

I've tried Googling the solution but to no avail. Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Are you signed in to Google from a US location? If so, it might just be trying to be helpful by translating the prices into US dollars for you.

Comment: I've checked on Chrome and Firefox (both incognito/private and signed in to my account with set location Australia) and it's still showing up the same. I'm guessing it's indexed in Google this way but from the varying product's HTML, they look similar yet some are showing up in USD and some in AUD. Other testers are seeing the same thing across Australia too.